# Where is the castle located in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I have been looking for the castle for awhile and I haven't found it yet. I have looked at the top right and top left of the Commonwealth map.I haven't been to the bottom part of the commonwealth.If anyone could help me with this problem I would appreciate it.Also don't tell me whats there I would like to find out on my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [wikia page on The Castle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Castle), you can find The Castle here:

[image: castle]

Comment: Vemonus I would like to ask you a question if you don't mind.

Comment: @Robert__garnet sure, what's up?

Comment: I know I ask a lot of questions about fallout 4 on this site but would it be fast or better to get the fallout wiki app. I like to ask on hear because people give me advice and tips on things that have to do with fallout 4. Plus I can use my knowledge to answer other peoples questions.I have never check the app out so would it be better to get it than to ask questions on this site.

Comment: @Robert__garnet it's up to you! It can benefit others in the future who have the same questions as you if you ask them on here but it may be faster for you to find things out via the wikia.

Comment: @Robert__garnet I would strongly advise checking the wiki first, and then only asking if you can't figure it out, or if it was difficult to figure out. If it was difficult, you can answer your own question to help others. If it was easy, then you're just wasting time by asking the question. This particular question would have been very easy. You also don't need the app, you can just check the website.